# What's the meaning of "explored" in DFS

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

[image]

I am tring to complete this tree where Iteration is clear, but i don't undertand how to find [tag:explored ] (on the table) or what is explored. I did't find any solution so can anyone explain what is explored or any source. my start state in A and goal state is E

Comment: It's a synonym for "visited".

Answer (score 0):

You can find the term "explore" being used in the context of tree traversals.

For instance in class notes from [TS University](http://cs.tsu.edu/ghemri/CS248/ClassNotes/Tree_Search.pdf), we find the terms "expanded", "explored", "visited", and "frontier" all used in an explanation of DFS in a (search) tree:

> expansion of nodes
>
> - as states are explored, the corresponding nodes are expanded by
>   applying the successor function
> - this generates a new set of (child) nodes
> - the fringe (frontier) is the set of nodes not yet visited
> - newly generated nodes are added to the fringe

Here you see how *exploring* happens at the moment of *expanding*: it is synonymous to *visiting*. Ignore the term "generated" here, as that is specific to *search* trees. You could read it as "discovered".

As the frontier consists of nodes that are by definition not yet visited, the set of explored nodes is disjunct from the set of nodes on the frontier. Furthermore, the nodes on the frontier are always direct children of the nodes that have been explored. The first node on the frontier will be moved to the explored set in the next iteration.

The table in your question can be completed as follows:

| Iteration | Frontier | Explored |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B,C,D | A |
| A,B,C,D | E,C,D | A,B |
| A,B,C,D,E | C,D | A,B,E |

#### Explanation:

Initially, we could say the frontier consists of A (not depicted in the table). It is the caller of the DFS algorithm that should pass this node reference.

In the first iteration the node A is popped from the frontier, marked as explored, and is *expanded*, i.e. its children are added to the frontier. So that means the frontier consists of B, C, and D.

In the second iteration the node B is popped from the frontier (from its left side), marked as explored, and is expanded: its children are added to the frontier (at its left side). The frontier thus becomes E, C, D.

In the third iteration the node E is popped from the frontier, marked as explored, and as this is the target node, the process stops. The frontier ends up with C, D still there, but these nodes will never be explored.